# cannot find method node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a js file like this

```
loader.js
exports.getConfig = function() {
   return config;
}
```

I am loading this file in other file as

```
var loader = require(__dirname + '/../../loader');
var config = loader.getConfig();
```

But I am getting error as Object has no method getCOnfig()
I checked the path the path in require is correct

Comment: I don't know Node too well, but don't you need `module.exports.getConfig = ...`?

Comment: @Ian exports is basicaly a helper for module.exports. module.exports will be called

Comment: Everything seems ok with your code (I even copied it and ran a test, just to be completely sure). I'm assuming this has to be an error with the path. That or it's something else you're not sharing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have made a **circular require**, it's not obvious,check it carefully:

If yes,learn more: https://coderwall.com/p/myzvmg

I say **circular require**,I mean suppose you have three module A,B,C. A require B,B require C,C require A. Yes,this is a circular require,this may cause strange error.

I don't know why somebody downvote my answer, I spent hours to figure out what happened when I get this error.I think this question probably is a **circular require** situation.

Comment: Yes I have made the circular require. I resolved it. It took some time. In node.js documentation. If I use require in a circular way. Uninitialised module will be passed and that is what was happening.

Comment: Node's error message is not so clear to tell you what happened, you need some experience to detect the problem.